# My server does not listen to port 25, even though iptables allows smtp traffic

Tags: linux, email, iptables, smtp, email-server

My public server accepts traffic and relays them to other machines on the network with iptables PREROUTING rules.
I recently added a mail server at 192.168.1.10 and made its iptables rules to accept port 25 traffic.

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT
```

With `netstat -nat` on the mail server I see it listens to :25

On my public machine, I added a

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 25 -j ACCEPT 
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10:25
```

rule, yet it does not listen to :25.
My university does not allow traffic into its network through :25, so when I telnet locally I get a connection refused error. The university's relay mail server is supposed to relay e-mails to user@site.uni.tld to my mail server (at :25), yet the connection fails

```
----- Transcript of session follows -----
<user@site.uni.tld>... Deferred: Connection refused by site.uni.tld.
Warning: message still undelivered after 4 hours
Will keep trying until message is 2 weeks old

Final-Recipient: RFC822; user@site.uni.tld
Action: delayed
Status: 4.4.1
Remote-MTA: DNS; site.uni.tld
```

Any ideas why? The DNS records are fine and have been transferred to the uni relay servers.

Comment: Can you give us the output of the following, so we can see what IP the MTA is listening on? netstat -an | grep ":25"

Comment: @furriephillips No output on the main server, and on the mail server: user@mail:~$ netstat -an | grep ":25" tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN tcp6 0 0 :::25 :::* LISTEN –

Comment: When you make an iptables DNAT rule, it doesn't make any listening sockets that netstat would show. The DNAT processing happens in a lower level of the network stack inside the kernel.

Comment: I'm assuming that "*I added a mail server*" means that the machine on which you're doing the `iptables` rules is the virtualisation host on which the new mail server image is running.  Is that right?  If so, you will need a `FORWARD` rule to ACCEPT the traffic, not an `INPUT` one.

Comment: Two great debugging tools for this are `iptables -L -nv` which shows hit counts next to each rule and `tcpdump -n port 25` which shows packets arriving on port 25 *before* they are processed by the firewall.

Answer (score 2):

An iptables PREROUTING rule will not show up in a standard netstat listing, as in NAT mode, it operates at the kernel level, therefore does not register as a process that's listening. The best way for you to diagnose this is to monitor all traffic on that machine on port 25 to see how it behaves with the rules you have in place;

`tcpdump -nn -i eth0 port 25`

(replacing `eth0` with the relevant interface name). This will show you all traffic coming to local port 25, or outbound to port 25 on a remote host (so you can look at it in both directions). If the traffic's not being sent on its merry way, your iptables rule is mangled and needs a closer look. If it is, then the problem's at the remote host.

Edit: forgot to add that you need the MASQUERADE chain setting up in POSTROUTING:

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

which will allow your internal device to communicate back with the outside world and reply to its clients.

Comment: No traffic in port 25. Are my iptables rules wrong then?

Comment: Not necessarily, it just means that your interface isn't receiving anything on that port. Keep tcpdump running and just telnet to that interface's IP address from another machine. The connect may/will refuse, but you'll at least see the SYN request in tcpdump. I also forgot to mention that you need the MASQUERADE chain setting up in POSTROUTING to allow the internal device to communicate with the outside world.